# How can I create global context variables in JBoss?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

This is a follow-up to a question I posted a while back:  "[Can I use a single WAR in multiple environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634458/can-i-use-a-single-war-file-in-multiple-environments-should-i)".  I was able to create a single-war solution in Tomcat, but now we are migrating our app to JBoss 4.2 and I can't figure out how to set up global environment variables.

In Tomcat 6 this was pretty straightforward:  I simply put the following snippet in `tomcat/conf/Catalina/myappname.xml`:

```
<Context ...>
   <Environment name="TARGET_ENV" value="DEV" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
</Context>
```

Then in my app I was able to resolve the environment name with the following:

```
Context context = (Context) InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
String targetEnvironment = (String) context.lookup("TARGET_ENV");
```

The problem is that I can't find out where/how to place global variables in JBoss.   I've tried putting the `<Environment>` tag in the following files to no avail:

- `server/all/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/context.xml`
- `server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/context.xml`

I know that I can put environment variables  in my app's web.xml but that defeats the purpose of having a unified war  - I'd still need custom .war's for dev, qa and prod.

I'm a JBoss newbie so if there's any additional information that would help just let me know and I'll append to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use somehing similar to [PropertiesService](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/PropertiesService) for database url, and other environment related things.

Therefore I'm relieved from the burden to provide different environment related atrifacts.

Comment: Properties service is an option, and it could work - but isn't it jboss specific?   It'd be nice to have a .ar that could potentially work in jboss *and* netbeans without modification to the .war itself.  Possible?

Comment: I developed a comparable service (resolving ${variables}) myself, the property files I place somewhere in classpath, therefore I don't face issues with dependencies on a specific application-server.

Comment: On "external properties in JBOSS" two questions:
1) Do you check-in the configuration file to your source control system?
2) How does the application know which configuration to use (DEV, TEST, UAT, PROD)?