# Configure a java spring project built by maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, configuration

I have a Java Spring web project. It is divided into several maven modules and projects. Currently, each artifact has an application-context.xml and a default.properties (so each project is runnable independantly.) I basically use annotation-based bean creation and @Value annotations for properties.

The aggregating webapp project has (of course) its pom and property files for each build target.

My problem is now: it feeld a little chaotic. The pom has several profiles, one for each build server, and contains properties needed by maven at build time (target server url) or properties that have to be replaced in config files (log4j smtp host). Then, I have the property file for each build system wheren I use the ${maven.variables} and overwrite default variables from included artifacts (like database, email config, etc).

The properties grew over time as many aspects are different between live and test server. It is difficult for new developers in the project to set up their project, although basically they should just use some kind of dev-default + your db credentials.

How do you handle properties for build/runtime?

Edit: another thing that annoys me: Properties can't be validated (if they exist, finding typos is a time consuming task...) currently. Maybere there is a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your maven project is setup for your build environment but I use the maven resource plugin for most projects.

Project structure (standard maven structure)

```
/Project
-/src
--/filters
---/filter.dev.properties
---/filter.test.properties
--/java
--/resources
---/config.properties
pom.xml
```

the config.properties (or other app config files) is used by the app code to configure itself. I have filter files for each environment that holds environment specific value only and these will replace the placeholders in config.properties

My POM file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/filters/filter.${env}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <env>dev</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <env>test</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Be default when I build locally I don't provide a profile to maven, it will use the filter.dev.properties, for building to test environment, in my Jenkins job I use the test profile.

Answer (score 0):

Vinh Ta's approach will work, but one issue that comes up is that you need to build a new artifact for each permutation (dev, test, production, etc). You could put all your property files in the src/main/resources directory (the resources plugin will automatically pick them up). Then you can control what version of the property file to use in Java using an environment variable.

```
/Project  
-/src/main/
--/resources/
---filter.dev.properties
---/filter.test.properties
pom.xml
```

Then you can build one artifact and deploy to multiple server by setting an environment variable on each server. This can also be done with java properties set on the command line too.

```
String resource = "filter"+System.getenv("ENV")+".properties";
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource);
```

One problem with the above approach (and Vinh Ta's) is that if you ever need to change these files, you will have to re-build or edit the artifact. If this is an issue, perhaps it is best to leave these property files out of the artifact and supply them to the application server externally. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634458/can-i-use-a-single-war-file-in-multiple-environments-should-i) for a solution.

As to validating properties. Yes, this is a problem. The closest thing I've seen is the [enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html).