# Persistence.xml field values from properties file

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, properties, persistence.xml

Help, i would like to my persistence xml properties value reference to my db.properties file.

here's my db.properties file

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apsas
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=password
```

and here's my current persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="apsaspu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>
            org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        </provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apsas" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

what i wanted to do is to set its property into like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="apsaspu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>
            org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        </provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

question is how can i import the properties file into my persistence xml
Advance thanks for those who will help me...

Comment: are you working with maven?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using maven, you can use source filtering for this. Use [this docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) for reference. I will outline the process a bit.

You will need to specify the filtering path. I am not sure if you have to explicitly define the included files.

```xml
<build>
  ...
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.xml</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
    ...
  </resources>
  ...
</build>
```

The directory you define is relative to the `pom.xml`.

You can now define regular maven properties to replace the placeholders in your `persistence.xml`

If you want to have the properties in a separate .properties file, you need to tell maven, where to find that file:

```
<filters>
  <filter>db.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

Filtering occurs on `mvn resources:resources`. This step is defined for all the packaging goals you will execute on deployment.

You can use maven profiles to switch between sets of properties or .properties files.

Comment: I try to move from resource filtering to system vars and properties file. [This guy explains why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1634545/660408)