# External web-application configuration in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

There's a web application and a number of environments in which it works. In each environment it has different settings like DB connection and SOAP ends-points that in their turn are defined in properties-files and accessed in the following way:

```
config.load(AppProp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
    PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH + PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME));
```

Thus the WAR-files are different for every environment.

What we need is to build a unified WAR-file that doesn't contain any configuration and works in any environment (for now, Tomcat instance) getting its configuration from outside its WAR-file.

The answer [Java Web Application Configuration Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568985/java-web-application-configuration-patterns), to my mind, gives the full set of common approaches but with just few examples. The most attractive way is configuring JNDI lookup mechanism. As I can guess it allows to separately configure web-applications by their context paths. But couldn't find a simple (step-by-step) instructions in both the Internet and the Tomcat's docs. Unfortunately cannot spend much time on studying this complicated stuff in order to just meet so seemingly simple and natural demand :(

Would appreciate your links at the relevant descriptions or any alternative suggestion on the problem.

Comment: *"Unfortunately cannot spend much time on studying this complicated stuff ..."* - Is that another way of saying "I have not done enough research"?

Comment: @Stephen C - exactly!

Answer (score 0):

If its a case of simply deploying your WAR on different environment (executed by different OS user), then you can put all your config files in the user's home folder and load them as:

```
config.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME));
```

This gives you the isolation and security and makes your WAR completely portable. Ideally though, you should still provide built-in default configuration if that makes sense in your case.

Comment: Don't think it's flexible enough :( In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568985/java-web-application-configuration-patterns  there's a version with a hardcoded absolute path. But what if we have two instances if Tomcat on the same box. Need something that configures the web-app inside the web-container.

Comment: Just start Tomcat with different users. 
Just curious what case yours is where you run the same app in two different Tomcat instances on the same box (presumably with different context paths???).

Answer (score 0):

The approach we've taken is based on our existing deployment method, namely to put the WAR files in the filesystem next to the Tomcat, and deploy a context.xml pointing to the WAR file to Tomcat.

The context descriptor allows for providing init parameters which is easily accessible in a servlet.  We've also done some work on making this work with CDI (for Glassfish and TomEE dependency injection).

If you only have a single WAR file deployed to this Tomcat instance, you can also  add init parameters to the default global context XML.  These will be global and you can then deploy the WAR file directly.  This is very useful during development.