# Place datasource password outside context.xml

Tags: java

Here is my context.xml -

```
<Context docBase=“myDB” path="/myDB" reloadable="true">
      <Resource name="jdbc/OracleDS"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@test.asia-pacific.com:1546:myTest”
          accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
          maxActive="10" 
          maxIdle="5" 
          maxwait="-1"
          removeAbandoned="true" 
          removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
          logAbandoned="true"/>
```

I don't want to add my DB username, and password to this file for security reasons. I have the below Java code -

```
Connection getConnection() {

    Connection con = null;
    DataSource ds = null;
    try {
        if (getJNDIName() != null) {

            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();                
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
            env.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
            Context initCtx = new InitialContext(env);
            Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

            ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup(getJNDIName());
            if (ds != null) {
                con = ds.getConnection();
            }
            if (ds == null || con == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "DataSource and/or Connection object is null.");
            }

            return con;
        } else if (cd_.con_ != null) {
            return cd_.con_;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
    }

    return null;
}
```

When I start my application, I am seeing below errors in the log file -

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:600)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:380)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:760)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:401)
```

If I put the username and password back in context.xml, it works like a charm. How do I put it outside the file. I would only want to put it in my Java class as the password will be encrypted, and not in xml since decrypting password from xml is not simple, and I don't want to get into it. Can someone please suggest how do I achieve this? Please

Comment: Let's say you manage to put the password in the Java file, encrypted. Where will you store the encryption key? I would store the password in the XML file, and only authorize read access to this file to the tomcat user and some other trusted users.

Comment: The encryption key is in my properties file. I can't afford to do that. Give restricted permission I mean.

Comment: So, instead of having a password in clear-text in an XML file, you have a key allowing to decrypt an encrupted password, in clear-text in a properties file. This seems like added complexity for nothing to me.

Comment: JB Nizet - I don't understand what you mean here. Can you give me an example?

Comment: You're concerned about a password to be stored in an xml file and thus be readable by anyone. So your solution is to encrypt it, and store the key in another properties file, still readable by anyone. So it doesn't add any security: anyone can still read the properties file, get the key, and decrypt the encrypted password. What you're doing is basically locking your house but leave the key under the doormat.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 7 context.xml support placeholder .
[dochere](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Property_replacements)

[Is it possible to use placeholder in context.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541731/is-it-possible-to-use-placeholder-in-context-xml)

In my project , i init my DataSource in an listener  which allow programe to read config option from an outfile or in the class.